# How to render file upload LWC in the middle of a conversation in Einstein Bot?

Tags: einstein, snap-ins

I am working in developing an Einstein Bot where after some discussion with the customer the bot would ask customer to upload an image or a document and then finally create a case along with with the uploaded file.

What I understood till now is we can render a LWC within Bot using lightningsnapin-base-chat-message. So I started by creating a lightning-file-upload LWC for uploading files and at embedded service deployments --> chat settings --> customize with lightning components , on Chat Messages used the file upload custom LWC.

On previewing the chat bot in community, I do see the file upload icon and it also uploads the chosen file.

***Question is how do I render the LWC after some conversation , now the file upload component comes at the start of conversation on top of menu options.***

It would be great if anyone has worked on a similar use case and might point out something which I may be missing here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this - https://debarunsengupta.medium.com/integrating-lwc-in-einstein-bot-1e5ffaeccc7c. Looks like it is same as your request.

In my project, I used the below option. But, in my Case, I haven't used Einstein BOTs. Check this link - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=live_agent_transfer_files.htm&type=5. In my Embedded Service deployment, I used custom LWC which implements "lightningsnapin/baseChatMessage".

Let me know if you have additional questions.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this is indeed possible this way and I was able to verify the same.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the confirmation Sagnik. 
Appreciate your response!

Comment: You should reproduce the important parts of those links here (links have a tendency to become unavailable, so link-only answers are of limited value)